# Add a column of data to dataset using table from a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my data set I am wanting to add the columns to.  Column Y is the column I want the data to be entered into.  Lets call this workbook "Dataset".

[image]

Below is my reference table I need to use from my workbook "Reference".  I need Column E "Dataset" to reference Column A "Reference" and produce Column B "Reference into Column Y "Dataset".  I have done some entry level SQL and python but I am not sure how to do this using VBA and can't seem to find an example online for this type of issue.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this type of query in excel VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP as cell function
2. Merge feature in PowerQuery (basically equivalent to SQL join)